Why is my light in the 2nd picture not as sharp as in the 1st?
why is the light on the 1st picture so sharp, and on the 2nd so scattered?
Area light - square is used on both pictures.
the 1st one is a screenshot from youtube, 2nd one is my work.
thank you very much for any help.



looking at the shadow of the walls on the external ground, it doesn't seem significantly different. The differences could be the light object's position, light size, or even just the materials it lights up that aren't the same and thus don't react the same to the light.

I don't see much of a difference either. It seems to me that there are different lighting conditions in those two images, because there are some shadows in one image that are not in the other, so of course different light locations and/or lamp types can create different shadows. But those which are in both images seem to have more or less the same sharpness.
